# React Redux Firebase Keep user logged in function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I added my login and logout functions and its working properly, but I don't know how to keep users logged in? Any quick advices? Thanks. This is my login logout actions:

```
export function logout_action() {
    return dispatch => {
        firebase.auth().signOut()
            .then(function () {
                const logged_value = null;
                dispatch(login({
                    ...logged_value
                }));
            }).catch(function (error) {
                // An error happened.
            });
    }
}

export function login_action() {
    return dispatch => {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
            const logged_value = result.user;
            dispatch(login({
                ...logged_value
            }));
        }).catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the `result` either on the redux store or save it in `window.localstorage` when the user logins in and when they logout you can delete the `result` from `window.localstorage` or the redux store.